# Uploading videos in blackberry

Tags: video, blackberry, upload

How to upload video files from BlackBerry device to server?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean programmatically, you'd need to make a java program, which will load the file and post it to a webserver. A script o the server can then store the videoclip.

Comment: Yes i mean programmatically only...means i have uploaded image to the server in the past...but i want to know if videos are to be uploaded the same way as images...is there any limit on how much data you can upload at one time...

Comment: There's no theoretical limit. Just remember that on the server side you have to make sure that you allow large files to be passed as post data. (php imposes some limits (8mb is standard if I remember correctly) which you might want to increase)